# Npm ignore dev dependency build errors looking for dev dependency

Tags: javascript, npm, webpack, build, dockerfile

So I want to ignore dev dependency in my dockerfile by adding the `RUN npm ci --only=production`. However, when the build is ran, it's looking for some of the packages that were listed in my `devDependencies` in package.json file.

Turns out there are bunch of packages required by `webpack.config` file. See error below.

[image]

Why is it doing this when they are dev packages? Should I be moving these packages to `dependencies` instead? (When I move them the error goes away but surely that can't be the right thing to do)

This is what the section of my dockerfile looks like:

```
COPY package*.json .npmrc ./
RUN npm ci --only=production

COPY . .
RUN NODE_ENV=production npm run build
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate `webpack.prod.config.js` that doesn't require any dev dependencies. You can have a `webpack.shared.config.js` for shared configuration between production and development config files.